# Companion object case object not accessible

Tags: scala

I'm using scala 2.12 and I try a piece of code that was coded in version 2.11 and it does not compile anymore :

```
object MusicController {
    sealed trait ControllerMsg
    case object Play extends ControllerMsg
    case object Stop extends ControllerMsg
}

// Music Controller
class MusicController extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case Play =>
            println("Music Started ...")
        case Stop =>
            println("Music Stopped ...")
    }
}
```

I have the following compiler error :

```
not found: value Play
[error]         case Play =>
not found: value Stop
[error]         case Stop =>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, as in: I can reproduce that the error occurs in 2.12, but I cannot reproduce that the error doesn't occur in 2.11. In fact, I am pretty sure that the error will occur in every version since at least 2.8, and probably at least in all 2.x versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import MusicController's case objects

```
object MusicController {
    sealed trait ControllerMsg
    case object Play extends ControllerMsg
    case object Stop extends ControllerMsg
}

// Music Controller
class MusicController extends Actor {
    import MusicController._ // <-- IMPORT THIS
    def receive = {
        case Play =>
            println("Music Started ...")
        case Stop =>
            println("Music Stopped ...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is working, but why is it like this now, it was working without import in 2.11, I thought also companion object properties were accessible from the companion class if both defined in the same file.

Comment: It does not work without import in 2.11 either (I've tested with 2.11.8). Are you sure you didn't have  import MusicController._ ? May be it was in the very top of the file? Or can you show the whole source?

Comment: I can't show the source it is a video I downloaded.  You are probably right about the import at the very top.  Thank you.